# operator == can not be applied to operand of type 'system.collections.generic.list<string>' and list

Tags: c#

Error "operator == can not be applied to operand of type 'system.collections.generic.list' and list

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test);
string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(test);
var pi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<read_json>(client);
List<string> id = pi.field_values[0];
if ( id== Convert.ToString(row[tid])) --------->Error //tid is integer which is fetched from a dataset table
{
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your code is testing to see if a string is equal to a list of strings.  That's not what the `==` operator does - it can't compare different types of objects, which is why you are getting that error.

Comment: What does this command do? "List<string> id = pi.field_values[0]";    saving the first index from array into id. am I right?   I want to compare the first inedx of field_values (the type of field value is list<string>) with id.  @Selman22,@shf301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are comparing a `List<string>` and a `string` for equality.  There is no such comparison available in C# hence an error is produced.  If you are attempting to determine if the `string` is present in the list then do the following instead

```
if (id.Contains(Convert.ToString(row[tid])))
```