# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, asp.net

help me get the items from the Dictionary according to the given list of lines

```
List<string> conversionTypeNames = Conversion1List
  .Select(k => k.ConversionTypeName)
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();

var query = new GoogleAdWordsData_Dictionaries_Query();
var ConversionsDict = query.GetConversionDictionary(ClientID);

ConversionsDict = ConversionsDict
  .Where(k => k.ConversionTypeName == conversionTypeNames);
```

Comment: Also error says everything you need to know.

Comment: `k => conversionTypeNames.Contains(k.ConversionTypeName)`?

Comment: C#. I would like to do without foreach
I'm interested in the way to implement this choice with linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [operator == can not be applied to operand of type 'system.collections.generic.list<string>' and list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654153/operator-can-not-be-applied-to-operand-of-type-system-collections-generic-li)

Answer (score 1):

So what i think you want to do is check if k.ConversionTypeName exists in conversionTypeNames, use this syntax

```
    ConversionsDict = ConversionsDict.Where(k => conversionTypeNames.Contains(k.ConversionTypeName));
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the right solution!

```
var new_Dict = ConversionsDict.Where(p => p.ConversionTypeName != null && !Conversion1List.Exists(a => a.ConversionTypeName == p.ConversionTypeName)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

here you create a list.

```
List<string> conversionTypeNames = Conversion1List
  .Select(k => k.ConversionTypeName)
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();
```

so try following Code to extract the list

```
foreach (var s in conversionTypeNames)
{
      ConversionsDict = ConversionsDict
     .Where(k => k.ConversionTypeName == s);    
}
```